# How to parse a csv file with a custom delimiter

Tags: python, pandas, parsing, delimiter

I have a csv file with a custom delimiter as "$&$" like this:

```
$&$value$&$,$&$type$&$,$&$text$&$
$&$N$&$,$&$N$&$,$&$text of the message$&$
$&$N$&$,$&$F$&$,$&$text of the message_2$&$
$&$B$&$,$&$N$&$,$&$text of the message_3$&$
```

and I'm not able to parse it with the following code:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('messages.csv', delimiter= '$\&$', engine='python)
```

can you help me, please??

Comment: Check out the docs regarding delimiter.
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html.
Another option, would be read in the file with open() and use string replace to replace '$\&$' with a delimeter that better suits your document maybe '|'

Comment: Can you edit your question and put there more rows from the file?

Comment: these are the three columns of the dataset

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:

> ... separators longer than 1 character and different from `'\s+'` will be interpreted as regular expressions and will also force the use of the Python parsing engine. Note that regex delimiters are prone to ignoring quoted data. Regex example: `'\r\t'`.

So, to fix your case it should be like this:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('messages.csv', delimiter= '\$\&\$,\$\&\$|\$\&\$', usecols=[1,2,3])
```

Note that there are going to be 2 additional columns, the first one and the last one. They exist because all data start/end with `$&$`. In addition to that, the delimiter is actually `$&$,$&$`. So, `usecols` get rid of them.

This is the output from the provided sample:

| value | type | text |
| --- | --- | --- |
| N | N | text of the message |

Comment: I did this and it worked! but there is a problem too! in column text just the first line of the text of that message remained and the other message lines of that row are missed!